# Asana API POST to Tasks leads to Server Error

Tags: node.js, api, asana

I'm using node.js and the api key for auth. All my get actions work, and I've been able to post a new project, but new tasks always return 'server error'. Here's the object I'm sending to the /tasks endpoint:

```
data: {
 name: 'Figure this out',
 notes: '',
 assignee: null,
 completed: false,
 assignee_status: 'later',
 completed_at: null,
 due_on: null,
 tags: [],
 parent: null,
 followers: [ { id: 5622986387066 }, { id: 5622895459066 } ],
 projects: [ 6156399090409 ],
 workspace: 1707039411020 
}
```

Any ideas? I've tried passing those ID values a variety of ways, and I've tried creating a more simple task, always fails with a 'server error' response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's the `"parent": null` that's causing the unhelpful `Server Error`, which definitely seems like a bug on our side - I've filed it and will hopefully get time to look into it soon. Trim that out, and it gives you actual error messages.

Just to save you some time: you can't set `completed_at` or `tags`, and followers should be just an array of integers (`"followers": [ 5622986387066, 5622895459066 ]`).

You can set `completed: [true/false]`, and the `completed_at` will be set to the time at which it was marked complete. Not being able to attach tags to a task is a known issue, and one we're hoping to rectify.

Additionally, it's just a little annoying that the format of a response doesn't map 1-1 to the format for posting/updating. We're hoping to do a pass on the overall design of the API to unify those parts a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Definitely required a little trial error to figure out what the api is looking for, but overall, I like the way you all are handling things. I'm getting the hang of it.